# Can I use a picture of a car for an album cover?

Tags: copyright, licensing

Assume I want to use a picture from unsplash of an old Dodge pickup for an album cover.

Can I use the picture without infringing on the car designer’s copyright? Would I need to obscure branding or get some sort of license?

Comment: What is unsplash?  (Using the image will not likely breach copyright as you are not passing yourself off as the car company or related to it.)

Comment: Unsplash is a free copyright free image site. Also, thanks!

Comment: IMHI - It should be OK to use as long as you are not profiting off the car company brand.  Reversing/manipulating the image won't help you legally.

Comment: But if I were to eventually sell the album I would profit off of it, and therefore the image....soooo

Comment: I doubt it would be a problem.  You are not selling cars or car parts which could be mistaken as being made by the company.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information.

Comment: @davidgo first of all: Don't answer in comments. Second: The car manufacturer is not the problem, it's the photographer - and that many of these 'picture libraries' don't have the right to license out pictures.

Comment: Please read the FAQs on [tag:copyright] before posting questions about copyright.

Answer (score 1):

Copyright applies to the *work*. A photo of a car is a work. The car manufacturer has no rights in the photo. The photographer holds the copyright by virtue of having made the photo until the copyright expires... about 50-70 years after the photographer's death.

To make a *derivate* of a work, you need to be either the rights-holder (e.g. the photographer) or acquire a license.

Whether a picture is positively given with a free license is hard to prove, especially since many many sites that host "free" pictures actually infringe copyrights and can't license the photos out - in such a case you'd have acquired a void license and thus infringed copyright.

Answer (score 1):

First, images from Unsplash are NOT free from copyright, just usage is free of charge when you either have a paid account or add the copyright line (something like © creator/unsplash ) to your work (here: album cover) directly next to the image.

But: at Unsplash, you can never be sure if the one who claims to be the creator actually IS the creator (and copyright holder), lots of images are lifted from real stock photo sites, so beware!

Second, a car is designed by humans and is, like a photograph or illustration, copyrighted for usually 70 years after the death of the creator or 100 years after the creation. Same applies to the logo on the car.

But, not all companies will chase copyright infringers when "old" cars are depicted; I know for sure that PORSCHE does and Volkswagen too, when vintage vans and beetles are involved. It might be a good idea to ask the manufacturer.

Comment: You apparently don't need to give attribution - https://unsplash.com/license